# Jest.fn defined variable is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, jestjs

I'm testing an AWS Lambda handler by checking if the callback function is called.

```
async function ingest(event, _, callback) {
    const a = someFunc(); //Can mock this out fine
    callback(null, response);
};
```

in my tests:

```
     it('should call the callback', async () => {
            const event = { message: 'some data'};
            const expectedResponse = { statusCode: 200, message: "test" };
            someFunc= jest.fn().mockReturnValue(expectedResponse)

            const context = {
                awsRequestId: 'test-request-id',
                functionName: 'test-function-name',
                getRemainingTimeInMillis: () => 5000, // return a fake remaining time
            };

            const callback = jest.fn();

            await handler(event, context, callback)
            expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null, expectedResponse);
        });
```

However I am getting `callback is not a function`

EDIT: I am also using middy to parse my lambda handler:

```
export const handler = middy(ingest).use(
    injectLambdaContext(logger, { clearState: true })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently middy deprecated callbacks in v2. It wasnt being passed through the middleware.